# How to find all files created in directory after a particular file was created?

Tags: shell, find

I have a file `ANIL.sh` created years back. I want to find files created after `ANIL.sh`.

I know how to find particular file using the `find` command. But I am not sure how to get files created after `ANIL.sh`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to restrict yourself to *regular files* (not directories etc.) and that you want to look in the directory `topdir` (which is where `ANIL.sh` also lives):

```
find topdir -type f -newer topdir/ANIL.sh
```

This would give you the pathnames of any regular file in or below `topdir` that has a *modification timestamp* later than the `ANIL.sh` file.

Creation time is not available on most Unix system.